# Page loading differently, window.location vs href:

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Hey still new to JS/CSS/HTML well basicly webdevelopment.
I have a page, for which I'm loading most of the stuff dynamicly. If i goto it by `window.location="mapmode.jsp"` Then it doesn't load properly but if I do an `<a href>` tag it loads fine.

Also if I do pagerefresh on the fine page, it loads in badly again.
Could be a jquerymobile thing maybe, but I'm just not sure..

The way I initialize the dynamic stuff might also be relevant so here it is:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#mapmode", function(event) {
    initPageHeader();
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

edit: mapmode.jsp:

```
<%-- 
    Document   : mapMode
    Created on : Jul 12, 2012, 10:36:22 AM
    Author     : ame
--%>

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head> 
        <title>Map</title> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css" />
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <!-- Start of first page -->
        <div data-role="page" id="mapmode" name="mapmode">

            <div data-role="header" id="header" name="header">

                                <p>TEEEST</p>
            </div><!-- /header -->

            <div data-role="content" id="mapmodePageContent" name="mapmodePageContent"> 
                <p>I'm the first page in mapMode!.</p>      

            </div><!-- /content -->
        </div><!-- /page -->



        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/LocalAction.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/firstPage.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/MenuLoader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/PageHeader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Mapmode.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please give more details about "doesn't load properly". What exactly happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile sidesteps your browsers linking and history. It automatically wires this up for links (`<a href>`). But for JavaScript you need to use their [`changePage` method](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html).

For example:

```
$.mobile.changePage('pagename.jsp');
```

See the linked documentation for more information and options when using `changePage`.

Comment: Works like a charm, but now my initpage doesn't trigger :)

Comment: @AndersMetnik Does your pagename.jsp have a DIV with a `data-role="page"`?